# Django CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect when using client on localhost

Tags: django, angular

I am using django 3.2 , i had implemented csrf using below link

[Link](https://www.procoding.org/jwt-token-as-httponly-cookie-in-django/)

Everything works fine when using same domain for client and server.

But while testing `locally` i get the error when sending post, put or delete requests.

I can see csrftoken in the request headers under cookie, but can't see it using document.cookie.

csrftoken is non httponly cookies, still i don't know why it not visible in document.cookie in client side.

Comment: i checked many answers related to this, but nothing helped!

Comment: did you test with locally added domain name to hosts file? I was wondering if it works that way too.

Comment: @FerhatMousavi sorry i didn't get you, i am running client on localhost and backend on some domain eg. `https://test.com`.

Comment: in Windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\Hosts` or in Linux `/etc/hosts` is your hosts file. You can add fake domain name on it and test locally with domain name. I just wonder what happen with locally domain name testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution,

Since my backend was running on other domain not on localhost.

I had added proxy for all the requests, so that they appear to be coming from same origin.

In Angular,  it ca be done like below:

proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/**": {
     "target": "<your backend url>",
     "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true
   }
}
```

then run using,
`ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["localhost:3000"]` inside your settings.py to allow post requests.

Comment: i had already added CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS as ["localhost:4200"], still i don't see the csrftoken i document.cookie

Comment: Are you running both on localhost ? , what is your local backend URL